# Rewrite rules for Run Jetty Run

Tags: url-rewriting, eclipse-plugin, embedded-jetty

I am trying to add a rewrite rule to my run jetty run Eclipse plugin. I am using Jetty v 8.1.2  and supply a 'jetty-rewrite.xml' in the 'Additional Jetty.xml' Eclipse run configuration option. What I would like to achieve is rewriting the following URL

```
/hello/world?id=1
```

to

```
/
```

The rewrite works in so far as my local URL is updated correctly. However, regardless of what URL I enter (regardless if it matches the rewrite pattern or not), I get a 404 File not Found error from jetty. Note that '/' is mapped to 'index.html' in my web.xml. I can enter any URL (even the full path to index.html) and I get the same 404 error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <!-- create and configure the rewrite handler -->
  <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
    <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
    <Set name="rewritePathInfo">false</Set>
    <Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>

    <!-- redirect the response. This is a redirect which is visible to the browser.
       After the redirect, the browser address bar will show /redirected -->
    <Call name="addRule">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule">
         <Set name="pattern">/hello/world/*</Set>
         <Set name="location">/</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>
  <!-- add the rewrite handler to the server -->
  <Set name="handler">
   <Ref id="Rewrite" />
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

I don't use any other jetty configuration files, except the default ones that are loaded by the run jetty run plugin. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I hadn't realized that `<Set name="handler">` essentially 'overwrites' my default handlers. So, to fix it, I changed the last few lines to

```
<!-- add the rewrite handler to the server -->
<Set name="handler">
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
  <Set name="handlers">
    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
      <Item>
        <Ref id="Rewrite" />
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Ref id="oldhandler"/>
      </Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</New>
</Set>
```

where `oldhandler` refers to a previously declared `<Get id="oldhandler" name="handler"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I use jetty9, and I edit two files:

1) start.ini
add one line: "--module=rewrite"

2) etc/jetty-rewrite.xml
add: 
    
     
      
      
      
      
      
        
          
            **/yyy/(.*)
            /$1**

Comment: Can this be used to redirect from /hello/world/* to /?